# How can I automate the process of checking of column and executing SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server, maintenance-plans

I am experiencing quite difficult problem and hope for your feedback. In my table I have a "Services"column in "MyData" table which contains names of my services. I have created SQL statement which should be executed via maintenance plan and get the minimum id value from one table and update "Value" column in "MyData" table:

```
declare @id int
select 
    @id = min(id) 
from 
    MyTable
where 
    MyTime >= dateadd(MM, -12, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate()),MONTH(getdate()),1))

update 
    MyData
set 
    Value = @id
where 
    ColumnName= 'MyServiceName'
```

The statement works correctly, but I need to automate the things. Problem is, I have several Services and it will be inefficient to manually change "MyServicename" column in where clause each time it is needed to be updated. I ask for your advice, how can I automate the process of checking the "MyServiceName" in order to execute the statement for appropriate service?
Sorry if it is written in too complicated way, but I hope could express the trouble I am expressing.

Comment: do you mean get all service names that need to be updated and then update all of them in one sentence?

Comment: Actually, I mean that service names should be updated by rotation. But if you have other ideas that can be useful I will be thankful)

Comment: is it possible to determine a maintenance period for each service? for example "every 6 month"

Comment: For now, it should be executed once a month. Don`t pay attention to "MM, -12" part of the query, it is just for testing

Comment: I't a bit confusing the mean of 'MyTable' and 'MyData'. In MyData (services table) you could set a 'last_maintenance_date' field. Just to know what services need to be updated. Then (I don't know the mean of MyTable.id), launch a cursor that updates record by record all affected rows and set `last_maintenance_date` again.

Comment: MyTable.id is a clustered index. Minimum id value is the value which is needed to update MyData.Value column, it holds the minimum id value from MyTable. Again, sorry for complicated explanation and thanks for the advice above. I will try to look what can be done with it.

Comment: I think you should use a cursor due you're using `min(id)`, but of course, if you're able to join MyTable.Id and MyData you can do it in one select/update sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear to me but

```
update 
    MyData
set 
    Value = @id
where 
    ColumnName in ('MyServiceName', 'MyServiceName2')
```